# Get a form's key value pairs when submitting with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

When a form is submitted I will prevent the default action and instead make an ajax call with the POST data.  How can I get all of the data so I can pass it along with my ajax call?

When a form element is submitted normally with the post method, it easily assembles all the `name => value` pairs in the form.  Unfortunately now that I am doing ajax, it looks like I need to assemble this myself. I really don't want to write JS to loop through a form and construct my own hash, I'm assuming there is an easier way with jQuery or some behavior I'm not thinking of.

A JS fiddle example of a form where I would need all values.
http://jsfiddle.net/rm9KD/

Comment: Usually $(form).serialize(); does the trick. It returns the form data in a query string that you can post to the server.

Comment: yea just found that - so useful. Thanks Greg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: url,
        data: $("form").serialize()
    }
);
```

*As you did not provide specific code, this is just an example for you to fill in*

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain what you would do instead?

Comment: wasn't me, but... i would vote to close instead

Comment: @Kevin B: Already closed :) Not sure why the downvote though. Simple question. Simple answer. Go figure :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) function that will serialize the form data into an array.  You can then take the resultant array and create a data object out of it.

```
var arrayData = $('#myForm').serializeArray(), 
    data = {}, 
    i = 0;
for(; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
    data[arrayData[i].name] = arrayData[i].value;
}
```

Alternatively, jQuery provides as [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function that provides a serialized string of the form data.

```
var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
```

Comment: Why serializeArray() instead of serialize()? Is it possible to just use the string from serialize() in the ajax's data field?

Comment: @DonnyP It is possible to use `serialize` as well, but if you want to manipulate the data before submitting it, `serialize` makes it a little harder to do that because it is a string value instead of an object.

Comment: Would the downvoter please comment on how I could improve this answer?  This is a perfectly viable answer as it provides two different ways to accomplish what the OP has requested.

Comment: Obviously someone in a bad mood today. Did the same to me. Oh well :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yeah.  I voted up your answer because I didn't think it deserved a downvote either.  People just tend to not read.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/WfrM4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        // Dont trigger a page load on submit.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get all the values of the form???
        var form_data = $('form[name="my_awesome_form"]').serialize()

        // Make an ajax call
        $.ajax({

            url: "/ajax_form_receiver",
            data: form_data
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If I may make one suggestion to improve this: You are already binding this to the form `submit` event.  Instead of `$('form[name="my_awesome_form"]')`, you could use `$(this)`.  No need to traverse the DOM when you already have a reference to what you want.